# How to push a new object into a JSON file using PHP

Tags: php, json

I would like to push new object inside a JSON file with PHP but I don't find any solution on internet due to the format.

Here is my Json file.

```
{
"html": {
    "snippet1": {
        "id":"snippet1",
        "title":"A title"
    },
    "snippet2": {
        "id":"snippet2",
        "title":"Another title"
    }
}
}
```

And here is the php file

```
$json = file_get_contents('./content.json');
$data = json_decode($json);

$id = "snippet3";
$title= "My title";
```

I expect to push those new data inside the JSON.

The result should be:

```
 {
"html": {
    "snippet1": {
        "id":"snippet1",
        "title":"A title"
    },
    "snippet2": {
        "id":"snippet2",
        "title":"Another title"
    },
    "snippet3": {
        "id":"snippet3",
        "title":"My title"
    }
}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have to make it an object? Just make it an array and items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('./content.json');
$data = json_decode($json, true); //added true to make it an array

$id = "snippet3";
$title = "My title";

$data['html'][$id]['id'] = $id; //add the id to the array
$data['html'][$id]['title'] = $title; //add the title to the array
$newData = json_encode($data, true); //turn the array back into json

$writeJson = file_put_contents("content.json", $newData); //write the json array to json file
```

Comment: That's killing me when it's that simple... That's work, thanks !

Comment: No problem at all.. Good luck 

Comment: There is a slight 'feature' as you don't need the second parameter to `json_encode($data, true)` as this is a flag and it equates to `JSON_HEX_TAG` - unless you really mean to include it.